# On which devices will the Kindle app post completion?

Tags: kindle, kindle-app

I have a laptop, iPad, windows phone and Kindle Paperwhite but am struggling to find a way to post to Facebok or Twitter when I have finished a book.

I just want to inform others about what I have read and let the authors know my rating but have only been able to do it though my old iPhone 4s and the basic non-keyboard Kindle.

Are there only certain platforms that this can be done?